# What happens with CPU context when Goroutines are switching?

Tags: multithreading, go, coroutine, goroutine

If I correctly understand how goroutines work on top of system threads -  they run from queue one by one. But does it mean that every goroutine loads\unloads it's context to CPU? If yes what's difference between system threads and goroutines?

The most significant problem is time-cost of context-switching. Is it correct?

What mechanism lays under detecting which data was requested by which goroutine? For example: I am sending request to DB from goroutine A and doesn't wait for response and at the same time occurred switch to a next goroutine. How system understands that a request came from A and not from B or C?

Comment: The "most significant problem" of _what_ is the "time-cost of context switching"? Goroutines are just a small stack, so switching goroutines is just swapping a couple pointers; there's no full "context-switch". I can't really figure out where your misconception lies in the last paragraph.

Comment: Which registers are touches by goroutines? 

Look. For example task/goroutines A is sending request to DB. Response is taking some time, and system already run text task. But when the data is come how system send it's to proper (A) task? How it's understand that they are for it?

Comment: a "DB request" isn't at the same level of abstraction as a goroutine. All function calls are synchronous, so return values just move up the stack inside goroutines; there's nothing different about a "DB request" in that sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Goroutines, memory and OS threads

Go has a segmented stack that grows as needed. Go runtime does the scheduling, not the OS. The runtime multiplexes the goroutines onto a relatively small number of real OS threads.

#### Goroutines switch cost

Goroutines are scheduled cooperatively and when a switch occurs, only 3 registers need to be saved/restored - Program Counter, Stack Pointer, and DX. From the OS's perspective Go program behaves as an event-driven program.

#### Goroutines and CPU

You cannot directly control the number of threads that the runtime will create. It is possible to set the number of processor cores used by the program by setting the variable GOMAXPROCS with a call of `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(n)`.

#### Program Counter

*and a completely different story*

In computing, a program is a specific set of ordered operations for a computer to perform. An instruction is an order given to a computer processor by a program. Within a computer, an address is a specific location in memory or storage. A program counter register is one of a small set of data holding places that the processor uses.

This is a different story of how programs work and communicate with each other and it doesn't directly relate to a goroutine topic.

Sources:

- http://blog.nindalf.com/how-goroutines-work/
- https://gobyexample.com/goroutines
- http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/30/goroutines-vs-threads/
- http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/program-counter

Answer (score 5):

### Gs, Ms, Ps

A "G" is simply a goroutine. It's represented by type g. When a goroutine exits, its g object is returned to a pool of free gs and can later be reused for some other goroutine.

An "M" is an OS thread that can be executing user Go code, runtime code, a system call, or be idle. It's represented by type m. There can be any number of Ms at a time since any number of threads may be blocked in system calls.

Finally, a "P" represents the resources required to execute user Go code, such as scheduler and memory allocator state. It's represented by type p. There are exactly GOMAXPROCS Ps. A P can be thought of like a CPU in the OS scheduler and the contents of the p type like per-CPU state. This is a good place to put state that needs to be sharded for efficiency, but doesn't need to be per-thread or per-goroutine.

The scheduler's job is to match up a G (the code to execute), an M (where to execute it), and a P (the rights and resources to execute it). When an M stops executing user Go code, for example by entering a system call, it returns its P to the idle P pool. In order to resume executing user Go code, for example on return from a system call, it must acquire a P from the idle pool.

All g, m, and p objects are heap allocated, but are never freed, so their memory remains type stable. As a result, the runtime can avoid write barriers in the depths of the scheduler.

### User stacks and system stacks

Every non-dead G has a user stack associated with it, which is what user Go code executes on. User stacks start small (e.g., 2K) and grow or shrink dynamically.

Every M has a system stack associated with it (also known as the M's "g0" stack because it's implemented as a stub G) and, on Unix platforms, a signal stack (also known as the M's "gsignal" stack). System and signal stacks cannot grow, but are large enough to execute runtime and cgo code (8K in a pure Go binary; system-allocated in a cgo binary).

Runtime code often temporarily switches to the system stack using systemstack, mcall, or asmcgocall to perform tasks that must not be preempted, that must not grow the user stack, or that switch user goroutines. Code running on the system stack is implicitly non-preemptible and the garbage collector does not scan system stacks. While running on the system stack, the current user stack is not used for execution.

### Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/HACKING.md