# Get Redis variable in different package in Golang

Tags: caching, go, redis

I'm using [go-redis/redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) and [go-redis/cache](https://github.com/go-redis/cache) to cache Go objects.

```
import (
    "communication/MQ_pkg"

    "gopkg.in/go-redis/cache.v3"
    "gopkg.in/vmihailenco/msgpack.v2"
)

obj := &VAR_STRUCT{}        

Codec.Set(&cache.Item{
            Key:    key,
            Object: obj,
        })
```

where obj is an structure having go maps(key value pair)
By Using above code i am setting a key and saving values into it. This is in package common.
Now i want to access this in different package say GetRedis_pkg without importing pkg. Is there are any way i can do that.
And can i access particular map inside that that structure by any means using redis key
imorted gopkg.in/go-redis/cache.v3 to use redis in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the same map by using a common `Codec` instance for both packages and both of set and get operations. For this purposes you need to implement a singleton instance producer. Desirably it should be a thread safe implementation. In this way you will save a lot of resource and guarantee connection correctness. This is significant to keep a client the only to prevent bugs and save resource.

> Client is a Redis client representing a pool of zero or more underlying connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

#### Singleton codec

```
package singleton

import (                       
    "sync"                     
    "gopkg.in/go-redis/cache.v5"
    "gopkg.in/redis.v5"
)                                                            

var codec *cache.Codec        
var once sync.Once             

func GetInstance() *cache.Codec {
    once.Do(func() {           
        client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     "localhost:6379",
            Password: "", // no password set
            DB:       0,  // use default DB
        })

        codec = &cache.Codec{
            Redis: client,

            Marshal: func(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
                return msgpack.Marshal(v)
            },
            Unmarshal: func(b []byte, v interface{}) error {
                return msgpack.Unmarshal(b, v)
            },
        }
    })                         
    return codec            
}
```

#### Set key using codec instance

```
package setter                           

import (                                         
    "github.com/Me/myapp/singleton"  
    "sync"                              
)                                       

func Set(keys []string, vals []SomeObj, wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    for i, k := range keys {            
        wg.Add(1)
        // singleton is thread safe and could be used with goroutines                       
        go func() {                     
            codec := single.GetInstance()

            codec.Set(&cache.Item{
                Key:        k,
                Object:     vals[i],
                Expiration: time.Hour,
            })
            wg.Done()                   
        }()                             
    }                                   
}
```

#### Get object using the same codec instance

```
package getter                           

import (                                         
    "github.com/Me/myapp/singleton"  
    "sync"                              
)                                       

func Set(keys []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) chan SomeObj {
    wanted_objs := make(chan *SomeObj)
    for i, k := range keys {            
        wg.Add(1)
        // singleton is thread safe and could be used with goroutines                       
        go func() {                     
            codec := singleton.GetInstance()
            wanted := new(SomeObj)
            if err := codec.Get(key, wanted); err == nil {
                wanted_objs <- wanted
            }
        }()
    }
    return wanted_objs
}
```

Comment: i have imported gopkg.in/go-redis/cache.v3 to use redis in my code

Comment: Ok, describe in your questions what the tools you are using and set an appropriate tags.

Comment: Yes I can and I'll improve it one more time. Don't wrap Go code to this html/js wrapper.

Comment: @vkc, Go doesn't use threads directly, see my answer about goroutines http://stackoverflow.com/a/41047899/629685. Yes,  this implementation is thread safe.

Comment: @vkc, if the answer works for you, please accept it.

Comment: its like partially working for me because i have to access particular variable/VALUE inside VAR_STRUCT using codec get

Comment: @l159 Yeah might be...check out example i have mentioned in question

Comment: So substitute it! If you expect that somebody will write code which you could just copy and paste, believe me it doesn't work like that.